# Static javascripts don't update in browser

Tags: javascript, symfony, google-chrome, symfony-3.3

I am using Symfony3 on Homestead and javascripts from my /web/static/js do not update in browser source. I 'am using Chrome and have checked `disable cache` option. Also I've remove existing cache in chrome. Any idea how to deal with it ? They are updating by some random time.

Comment: Are you also using any cdn ? Or is this some local setup ?

Comment: is it not updating or you didn't manage to import it into view ?

Comment: I have local setup. I had /web/static/xyz.js and if I do some new stuff inside it didn't change in the browser like I am getting old cached version.

Comment: did you cleared cache? php bin/console c:c ? are you using any js compiler like gulp or grunt ?

Comment: have you tested it on incognito mode

Comment: Yes I've clean cache with symfony also tried manualy with rm -rf /var/cache/* ... i don't use any compiler. In incognito mode there is no diffrence. I have no idea what is the reason